# FPS slowing down significantly when using frame by frame animation

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

I am developing a game for the Android platform using flash cs5 and AS3.

problem: the game will run at 24-29 fps until I call a movieClip that has frame by frame animation, then it will drop to 10-14 FPS. 
It looks perfect on my PC and does not lose frames until I move it to my Evo for testing. I have tested on an Epic also and I do not lose Frames which leads me to believe that it is the pixil population in the evo that is causing the problem but I have tried everything I can think of to not make it so intense on the graphics but same results every time.

It's a 20 frame animation and my FPS in flash is set to 24

What I have tried:

png's on each frame |
gif's on each frame |
pen tool vector drawing of each image on each frame |
tween instead of frame by frame |
static image in the movie clip and creating a loop in AS3 that will cycle through the images |
onEnterFrame |

The only thing that actually does make it smooth is having the same image on each frame. This is why I believe it is the graphics and not the processor.

```
**Benchmark on PC :** 
FPS: 24/24
FPS DURING ANIMATION: 24/24

MS: 33
MS DURING ANIMATION: 33

MEMORY: 18.87
MEMORY DURING ANIMATION: 19.27

**Benchmark on Evo :** 
FPS: 24/24
FPS DURING ANIMATION: 13/24

MS: 36
MS DURING ANIMATION: 80

MEMORY: 2.931
MEMORY DURING ANIMATION: 2.993
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use vector: it's terrible. What you need to do is use the cacheAsBitmapMatrix method, but this is available only if you're publishing using the AIR for android publish settings.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap

Also a video tutorial about taking advantage of GPU acceleration on mobile/android that walks you through benchmarks and implementation:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=132

And as a last update to the answer, here is a great article comparing all these methods of drawing on the android platform + benchmarks:

http://labs.byhook.com/2011/01/13/digital-sheep-air-for-android-drawing-performance/

It discusses at length the different implementations and why some are better/worse than others.

Comment: The flash game programmers found out a while back that cacheAsBitmap is not a big increase in performance on anything that moves/animates/etc. only static images (like vector drawn backgrounds). How that relates to the mobile devices I have no idea. Nice resource links. + 1

Comment: Well with all due respect if you don't have any idea then please don't comment, because you confuse people looking for the right answer. Next time before you try and correct someone, can you please take the time to read the answer in full, do the research, test, and then give a conclusion? This isn't cacheAsBitmap, it's a new method added specifically for mobile called cacheAsBitmapMatrix and it accepts a matrix object. If you had of watched the video tutorial or read any of my links you would see it actually makes a HUGE difference in performance.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh but it just appears that you didn't really even read my answer before commenting.

Comment: Okay no problem again I just realized after typing my answer that I sound like a complete ******* bleeping bleepity bleep I apologize I read it all wrong. :)

Comment: heh, No your 100% right I commented before I double checked. Those are interesting reads (and an interesting video).

Comment: Thank you Ascension Systems, you totally saved me. I am going through the videos now and he is explaining my exact symptoms and using the hardware acceleration looks like it will be the fix to all my problems and opens up a whole new outlook on just how much I can push the GPU. Thanks again man.

Comment: No problem at all. Even better news, in a couple of months they're going to be updating AIR for android to use the new Flash Molehill API's (full blow, raw GPU access) and it's just going to get plain retarded what you can do with flash not only on desktop but mobile too. Links: http://away3d.com/, http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/features/molehill.html, http://alternativaplatform.com/en/showcase/.

Comment: Unfortunately, This does not accelerate frame by frame animations. I might... and that is a strong might... be able to accomplish this in AS3 without the frame by frame but I am looking into learning papervision3d to see if that will help me. Still really great resources Ascension. Future games will be easier with these techniques.

Comment: Don't look at papervision3D it's a dead project. Yes there is a "Newer" branch called papervision 3d3 but trust me, it's essentially a dead project. Lets put it this way, 3D engine developers were invited to be involved in a private alpha/beta of the new molehill API's (away3d, alternativa etc) and papervision3D was not invited. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538354/actionscript-3d-engine/5538417#5538417.

Comment: hah... that was a great read... you saved me again... The worse part about developing for flash and AS3 is that you never really feel like you are using it to it's full potential. There are so many frameworks and investing learning time into them can be a dire choice. Wasted time on dead frameworks can really drop you behind the herd.