# Actionscript 3D engine

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, 3d

I'm new to 3D, so asking for help. I need to make walking simulator on AS3: first-person view, moving through rooms and corridors. I don't need any physics, only moving and looking. Could someone tell me, what's the best actionscript-3 3d framework to implement needed functionality? Explanation is welcome :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Away3D. Best open source (and probably best of all) 3D engine on flash. You can either do this using the old away3D version for flash player 10 and under, or using away3D for the new Molehill 3D api's. Links:

Away3D 4.0 (Molehill APIS)

http://away3d.com/

Away3D 3.5 For Flash 10 and under

http://away3d.com/away3d-3-5-0-2-5-0-released

Post on an animated walk-cycle done programatically in real-time using (I believe) away3d. Also discusses pros/cons somewhat of away3d.

http://www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/09/making-things-walk-in-flash-3d/

Also the away3D SVN is packed full of demo's with source code for all of these things you see in the links + much more.

http://code.google.com/p/away3d/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Note that the broomstick branch in the trunk is the away3D 4.0 branch, targeting the beta flash player 11. More NFO on that here:

http://blog.ascensionsystems.ca/?p=147

Answer (score 2):

I see that [Away 3d](http://away3d.com/) has been mentioned already

the other options are [Alternativa](http://blog.alternativaplatform.com/en/) and [nd3d](http://www.nulldesign.de/projects/nd3d-as3-3d-engine/)

beyond that you might want to look into [flare3d](http://www.flare3d.com/) and unity3d.

Papervision looks like it's not keeping with times, but pretty similar to away3d, more resources()tutorials), but no molehill APIs

Comment: I'd argue that papervision doesn't have more tutorials etc. Papervision has been a written-off option for more than a year, and it's even to the point that it's basically considered a dead project. Away3D started by breaking off from papervision quite some time ago by an astrophysicist who then began steamrolling them out with advanced features and performance. There was actually quite a feud over it and many of the core papervision developers took a fit and quit developing all together. To be honest I would too, trying to go head-to-head with an astrophysicist seems pointless.